# Can't read database included with pyinstaller after compiling

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyinstaller

I have a fully functional program that can read a database in the same directory, and I need to get it all into a single binary file. To do this, I'm using pyinstaller, and am specifying the database in the datas section of the spec file.

```
a = Analysis(['MyProgram.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('db_MyProgram.db','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

When I run the pyinstaller command with the spec file (pyinstaller --onefile MyProgram.spec), there are no issues. However, the exe doesn't seem to know how to access the included database. I think it has to do with how I reference it inside of the original python file:

```
db_path = db_MyProgram.db
conn = sql.connect(db_path)
conn.close()
```

When I run the exe, if it is not in the directory with the original database, it makes a new database, and tries to use that instead of the included one. However, if it is run in a directory with the correct database, it will access it, and work like normal.

I have looked up the pyinstaller docs for how to use spec files, I've looked up how to access files included with pyinstaller, (all I've found was how to add them). And I've tried making adding the database in several different ways. Nothing has worked to make it access the included database.

Comment: Are you using a path, or are you assuming the "current directory" is the one containing the database?  You probably need to compute the correct path using `os.dirname(__file__)`.

Comment: I thought that I was including it in the same folder as the main program, is that not the case?

Comment: I have tried adding the database with the full path, and that hasn't changed it.

Comment: Perhaps so, but when you open a file using just the file name, Python looks in the "current directory", NOT the directory that contains the executable.  As I said, opening `os.dirname(__file__) +'/db_MyProgram.db'` should get you close.